# I can't make event.key statement work

Tags: python, pygame

the first if statement under (if event.type = KEYDOWN) is executed but the third
one doesn't seems to. I want the if statement to execute when  I press the plus key and when the string variable is non-empty.

```
from pygame import init, display, font
from pygame.event import get as event_getter
from pygame.locals import *
import time
init()
surf = display.set_mode((400,400))
string =""
num = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
adder = ""
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    surf.fill((0, )*3)
    for event in event_getter():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                string = string[:-1]
                print("backspace")
            if str(event.unicode) in num:
                string += str(event.unicode)
                print("num")
            if event.key == K_PLUS and len(string) >0:
                adder = string
                string = ""
                print(adder)

    surf.blit(font.Font(None,50).render(string,1,(255, )*3),(100,100))
    display.flip()
```

Comment: have you tried placing `print(repr(event.key), repr(string))` just before the problematic `if`?

Comment: Though this doesn't actually answer the question, empty strings are falsy and non-empty strings are truthy in python, making `len(string)>0` unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get K_PLUS to work either on windows, so it may be best to simply use the key code.  Run the code below, when you press a key you will see the integer value for the key code. (Currently the value is set to 61, which I believe is the code for a British keyboard layout, but it seems that a value of 45 works for other keyboard layouts)

```
from pygame import init, display, font
from pygame.event import get as event_getter
from pygame.locals import *
import time
init()
surf = display.set_mode((400,400))
string =""
num = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
adder = ""
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    surf.fill((0, )*3)
    for event in event_getter():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            print("Event key: %s" % (event.key))
            if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                string = string[:-1]
                print("backspace")
            if str(event.unicode) in num:
                string += str(event.unicode)
                print("num")
            if event.key == 61 and len(string) >0:
                print("+ pressed")
                adder = string
                string = ""
                print(adder)

    surf.blit(font.Font(None,50).render(string,1,(255, )*3),(100,100))
    display.flip()
```

Comment: the code works now by replacing K_PLUS by the key code which is 45 on my windows. Thanks for the help

Comment: hmm, this might be because I am using a British keyboard layout.  I just checked the value of "K_PLUS" and it is 43.  Make sure you keep this in mind if you use your program on different computers :)

Answer (score 0):

"shift =" is "+". 
ord('=') is 61 
Better do it properly as following:

```
mods = pygame.key.get_mods()
if event.key ==pygame.K_KP_PLUS or (event.key==ord('=') and mods & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT):    # "shift =" is "+" 
  print("+ pressed")
```